# BEM And Layout Rich Texts

Tags: html, layout, sass, components, bem

I read [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/06/battling-bem-extended-edition-common-problems-and-how-to-avoid-them/) that it is a good BEM practise to use layout components to arrange the flow and positioning of other components. The resource suggests the following example:

```
   <ul class="l-grid">
       <li class="l-grid__item">
           <div class="c-card">
               <div class="c-card__header">
                   […]
               </div>
               <div class="c-card__body">
                   […]
               </div>
           </div>
       </li>
       <li class="l-grid__item">
           <div class="c-card">
               <div class="c-card__header">
                   […]
               </div>
               <div class="c-card__body">
                   […]
               </div>
           </div>
       </li>
   </ul>
```

While the above makes perfect sense, I'm not sure on how to apply this approach to a typical block based page flow such as the listed below:

```
        <section class="c-page-section c-page-section--white-bg">

           <div class="l-container">

               <h1 class="c-page-section__title">Page Title</h1>
               <hr class="c-separator c-page-section__separator">

               <p class="c-paragraph">
                   ...
               </p>
               <p class="c-paragraph">
                   ...
               </p>
               <p class="c-paragraph">
                   ...
               </p>
               <ul class="l-horizontal-list">
                   <li class="l-horizontal-list__item c-tag">Java</li>
                   <li class="l-horizontal-list__item c-tag">PHP</li>
                   <li class="l-horizontal-list__item c-tag">HTML</li>
                   <li class="l-horizontal-list__item c-tag">CSS/SASS</li>
               </ul>

           </div>

    </section>
```

I am uncertain whether to apply margins inside the `h1`, `hr` and `p` based c-components or to create additional layout components around the them?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BEM is a good tool to layout a website, it is also an excellent tool to structure the appearance of a web application. But, use BEM to style rich texts? It's just... not the good tool.

I suggest you to create a *"not BEM component"*, named `rich-text`, with cascades:

```
.rich-text p {
  /* style here, including margins and paddings */
}
.rich-text hr {
  /* style here, including margins and paddings */
}
.rich-text ul {
  /* style here, including margins and paddings */
}
.rich-text ul > li {
  /* style here, including margins and paddings */
}
// etc.
```

And in your HTML code:

```
    <section class="c-page-section c-page-section--white-bg">
       <div class="l-container rich-text">
           <h1>Page Title</h1>
           <hr>
           <p> ... </p>
           <p> ... </p>
           <p> ... </p>
           <ul>
               <li>Java</li>
               <li>PHP</li>
               <li>HTML</li>
               <li>CSS/SASS</li>
           </ul>
       </div>
    </section>
```

Then, you have to remember that other BEM components cannot be nested into this `rich-text` component (because of cascades). But even with the BEM methodology you could not nest any component anywhere in a richtext. Due to the semantic limitation of tags `<p>` or `<em>` that cannot embed `<div>` for example.

Notice: I suggest to not style `.rich-text` itself as a block: no `padding` neither `margin` or `background`. It is more reusable if all properties of the rich text component are only about the rich text elements. You could need to display several rich texts in the page and they won't share the same background or paddings. If you need to display the rich text in a white rectangle with borders, just create a true BEM component for that and make it a container of the rich text.

Comment: Thanks @Paleo. So I should apply the .rich-text methodology for positioning standard tags (p, hr, ul, h1, etc.) inside rich tags only? When do I make use of layout components then? I guess for more complicated scenarios such as a grid system with multiple columns?

Comment: @AndreasLukas > _"positioning standard tags (p, hr, ul, h1, etc.) inside rich tags only"_ This is what I do. It is a good way to work with a content produced by an editor like TinyMCE for example. The special component `.rich-text` is an exception for BEM.

Comment: I see, when however would you make use of layout components such as the example I showed in my question above?

Comment: The grid system doesn't work inside the `.rich-text` component, right? The `.rich-text` component simply take the dimension and the position of its parent. The parent can be positioned and dimensioned as a BEM component (or element) that follows a grid.

Comment: Oh I finally understood what you meant :) Thank you!

Comment: Sorry one more thing :) You said that `other BEM components cannot be nested into this rich-text component (because of cascades)`, which makes absolute sense. However, what if I want to use BEM components inside the `.rich-text` in order to layout those as well. Instead, you could replace the `.rich-text ul` with `.rich-text + ul` to prevent cascading (assuming the `ul` has a BEM class attached in that case).

Comment: Not `.rich-text + ul` but `.rich-text > ul` (the child selector). But then you have to think to all the cases: `<ul>` or `<p>` inside a `<blockquote>` etc. I'm unsure if it is possible to cover all the cases. But why not. I personally use nested components _"richtext-proof"_, like a `.inline-fig` component (for an image with a caption but not in a `<figure>` element) and I verify that the cascade rules don't interfere with it.