# Elements without class name?

Tags: css, bem

I have a super simple question, are children elements allowed to be classless in [BEM](http://getbem.com/introduction/) CSS methodology?

So, is this code valid:

```
<div class="foo__label">
  <p class="foo__text">Something <strong>else</strong></p>
</div>
```

Or maybe it should be written as:

```
<div class="foo__label">
  <p class="foo__text">Something <strong class="foo__text-strong">else</strong></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Your first example is fine. In your second example you only need to add a class if you plan to create CSS for it. `class="foo__text-strong"` is needed if you need it to be.

Comment: The point of it all is to prevent "style-leakage" and add reusability and ease-of-use for your co-workers. So, in general I would say it's ok to write `.foo__text > strong{color:red}`, it would not leak or have any other nasty side-effect. Adding `.foo__text-strong` is probably overkill. Specific rules could be written in your company's guidelines.

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46318128/3786294 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will allow myself to quote @Intervalia:

> Your first example is fine. In your second example you only need to
>   add a class if you plan to create CSS for it. class="foo__text-strong"
>   is needed if you need it to be.

His comment **perfectly answers** your question. However I would like to add another scenario which may come in handy.

It is regarding user generated content from a CMS (worpdress for example). In this scenario the user is usually writing content in WYSIWYG editor and can not add BEM classes or even the user is not so advanced to know about them.

In this case is perfectly fine to have a "parent" element in which you can style elements by tags.

Examples:

```
.text ul{}
.text p{}
.text iframe{}
.text img{}
.text strong, .text b{}
.text em, .text i{}
.text a{}
```

---

**UPDATE 1:** Info on using nested selectors:

> Nested selectors increase code coupling and make reuse impossible. The
>   BEM methodology allows using nested selectors, but we recommend
>   minimizing their use.
>   https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#can-i-use-nested-selectors

So yeah if you think it is overkill you may go with @Rene's suggestion.

**UPDATE 2:** Helper Classes.

> The BEM methodology doesn't have strict rules for creating helper
>   blocks. A lot depends on specific implementations and the personal
>   preferences of the developer. An example of a helper block in bem-core is the `clearfix` block.
>   https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#can-i-create-helper-classes

Perhaps this technique can help? Personally I always have few global helpers which I use a lot.

Example, the famous Screen Reader only styles:

```
.sr-only{
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
    height: 1px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    clip: rect(0,0,0,0);
    border: 0;
}
```

In your case you can define for example `.accent-color` or simply `.accent` which can turn any element's color into red or whatever :)

Comment: I'm afraid I wasn't specific enough. I want the strong to have different colour. My question remains - do I really NEED the class just for colour change? Seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: @Wordpressor Not necessary, you can target that specific element in a different way, but in general it's just a personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cascade `.foo__text strong` if you are aware that:

1. It is not BEM compliant;
2. It wouldn't be possible to add a nested block with a `<strong>` element as a children of `.foo__text`.

Regarding the second point, the semantic of `<p>` element already has limitations. Your cascade just adds one: no `<div>`, no `<ul>` as child (because the parent is a paragraph)... and then in your case no BEM block that could have a `<strong>` element.

So, if you're not a purist, why not.

See also: [BEM And Layout Rich Texts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307349/bem-and-layout-rich-texts)